# How to do mathematics when "=" button is pressed?

Tags: javascript

When creating a calculator generally using a switch statement works for adding,subtracting etc, in this scenario I am not sure where the Switch statement would go or if its needed, so that the calculator can do its mathematics?

```js
const screen = document.getElementById('screen');
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (const btns of btn) {
  //press button by index
  btns.addEventListener("click", (num) => {
    const numValue = num.target.innerText;
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(numValue);

    if(numValue === "="){
      
    }

    screen.appendChild(textNode)
    
  });
  
}
switch(numValue){
      case "+":
        num + num
        break;
      case "-":
        num - num
        break;
      case "/":
        num / num
        break;
      case "*":
        num * num
        break;
      case "*":
        num - num
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error")
    }
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div>
<div>
<button class="btn">+</button>
```

Comment: Much more important (than "*where exactly does the `switch` statement go*"): what is `num` (i.e. where does it come from), why are you using it twice, and what do you want to do with the result of the calculation (that currently is not assigned to anything)?

Comment: I made you a snppet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]. I suggest you use delegation instead of looping the event listeners

Comment: check my code if it works or not and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

let currentInput = "";

//add event listeners to all buttons
for (const btn of buttons) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  //get the text content of the clicked button
    const buttonText = event.target.innerText;
    //check the button pressed
    switch (buttonText) {
      case "=":
        //if "=" is pressed, calculate the result
        const result = calculateResult(currentInput);
        screen.value = result;
        currentInput = result;
        break;
      case "+":
      case "-":
      case "*":
      case "/":
        //append the operator to the current input
        currentInput += ` ${buttonText} `;
        screen.value = currentInput;
        break;
      default:
        //append the pressed button value to the current input
        currentInput += buttonText;
        screen.value = currentInput;
    }
  });
}

function calculateResult(input) {
  try {
    return Function(`'use strict'; return (${input})`)();
  } catch (error) {
    return "Error";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="screen" readonly>
  <div>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>+</button>
    <br>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>-</button>
    <br>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>*</button>
    <br>
    <button>0</button>
    <button>/</button>
    <button>=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the for loop: `buttonContainer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {` same code